# fopen permission problem in php

Tags: php

open function working in local server but not working on mail server

Comment: Please post some code or otherwise expand on the issue you are having.

Answer (score 2):

*Very popular trouble:*

Your local server works under Windows OS, so you can access your file without any trouble. But when you migrate from Windows to Linux, FreeBSD or other hosting you get "Access denied" error. So, you need to change access permissions to your file with FTP client or SSH.

Google for [changing file permission](http://www.google.com/search?q=changing+file+permissions). You will get a lot of step-by-step instructions for chmod linux command, SSH and s.o.

It will be much better, you post here some PHP output, such as warnings or errors.

Answer (score 1):

[Like Andrew said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499006/fopen-permission-problem-in-php/2499083#2499083), it's probably a file permission problem.
If you're trying to open a remote resource (using a network protocol), you should check your `phpinfo()`: the configuration key `allow_url_fopen` must be set to `on`.

Could you copy/paste more details about your problem?

- PHP version
- complete error trace
- file permissions